# Word for "things that make you laugh"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, jokes

Is there an English word or phrase that describes a particular type of moment or thing that would make you laugh or enjoy?

For example,

> Some people might think animals are funny, but it might be boring for you, because animals are not your ___.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific word for 'things you find _funny_'.

Comment: *not funny to you* would be more typical, or there are many other ways of expressing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an English word or phrase that describes a particular type of **moment or thing that would make you laugh or enjoy**?

For a single word for *joy/pleasure*  we have

> **Delight** (n.)
>
> Something that gives great pleasure
>
> *Her performance was a delight* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delight)

> COUNTABLE NOUN
>
> You can refer to someone or something that gives you great pleasure or
> enjoyment as a delight.
>
> *The aircraft was a delight to fly.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/delight)

For a single word for certain types of *enjoyment/humor* we have (in AmE)

> **Hoot** (n)
>
> Something or someone amusing
>
> *The play is a real hoot.* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoot)

(If someone tells me that they found something a hoot, I would think it is more on the side of laugh-provoking than simply amusing.)

Answer (score 1):

There is the informal expression *it's not (really) my/your thing* ( with the variants *[not my bag](https://www.google.com/search?q=not%20my%20bag%20meaning&oq=NOT%20MY%20BAG%20ME&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i22i30l2j0i15i22i30j0i22i30l4j0i390.6190j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), [not my cup of tea](https://www.google.com/search?q=not%20my%20cup%20of%20tea%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsbw7S9PDLK-ehUotGM2jZs8MQl9Hw%3A1663226634419&ei=CtMiY-aRGaiGhbIPzK-imAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjmvuaFopb6AhUoQ0EAHcyXCEMQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=not%20my%20cup%20of%20tea%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIICAAQHhAPEAcyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CggAEEcQ1gQQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ_QdYhhxg1yNoAnABeACAAVaIAfoFkgECMTGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*). You hear that in adverts sometimes. [Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+your+thing#:%7E:text=not%20your%20thing) defines it as:

> Not something one particularly enjoys or is good at;  it is not something that you really enjoy or are interested in:
>
> - If skiing's ***not your thing***, Soldier Hollow also offers snowshoeing and a lift-served tubing hill, plus rental equipment. ([Soldier Hollow](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Soldier+Hollow.+(Tips+%26+Trips)-a094842987))

You could also turn the sentence round and say:

> because you are ***not a (big) fan*** of animals...

> a fan of (someone or something)
> Someone who strongly likes, appreciates, supports, or is interested in someone or something.
>
> - Sorry, but I'm ***not really a fan*** of Art Deco. ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+fan+of+something))